# [TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Imports argument must be present and must be an object]

Tags: node.js, go, webassembly

I'm trying to import a golang WebAssembly component into NodeJS but keep hitting this problem:

`[TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Imports argument must be present and must be an object]`

I think the problem is that I need to find a way to include the `wasm_exec.js` since it works in the Chrome.

Here's what I have tested:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const buf = fs.readFileSync('./test.wasm');

async function asyncCall() {

    try {
        //listing messages in users mailbox 
          const lib = await WebAssembly.instantiate(new Uint8Array(buf)).then(res => res.instance.exports);

        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }

    console.log(res);
    // expected output: 'resolved'
  }

  asyncCall();
```

Comment: You're missing the second argument to WebAssembly.instantiate().

Comment: Arh thanks. Is this the wasm_exec.js file? If so how would I do this ?